# canonical projection $\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the canonical projection $\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$? How can I specify this map explicitly?

Comment: $\overline{x}\mapsto \overline{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply: $\,x+p^{n+1}\mathbf Z\mapsto x+p^n \mathbf Z$.

Comment: Why is this independent of the representative?

Comment: because if $x \equiv y \pmod{p^{n+1}}$, then $x \equiv y \pmod{p^n}$.